# Syntax error in MySQL function while running code

Tags: php, mysql, function, phpmyadmin

I am getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

when i run followed code in phpmyadmin also appearing this error beside of second declare expression:

> unrecognized statement type (near declare)

What can be cause of these error? (Phpmyadmin, version, etc)

```
create function fnc_generate_url(title_in varchar(250))
    returns varchar(250)
        begin
            declare v_count int; 
            declare v_return varchar(250);
            declare cr_count cursor
            for
                select count(1) from tbl_page where page_title like concat('%',title_in,'%');

            open cr_count;
                fetch cr_count into v_count;
            close cr_count;

            if v_count = 0 then
                set v_return = replace(trim(title_in), ' ', '-');
            else
                set v_return =  concat(replace(trim(title_in), ' ', '-'),'-',v_count);
            end if;

            return v_return;
        end;
```

Comment: You might merely need a `delimiter` statement before the function.

Comment: Actually, i had added before, i was still getting the same error when exists delimiter expression in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine if we use delimiters.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
create function fnc_generate_url(title_in varchar(250))
    returns varchar(250)
        begin
            declare v_count int; 
            declare v_return varchar(250);
            declare cr_count cursor
            for
                select count(1) from tbl_page where page_title like concat('%',title_in,'%');

            open cr_count;
                fetch cr_count into v_count;
            close cr_count;

            if v_count = 0 then
                set v_return = replace(trim(title_in), ' ', '-');
            else
                set v_return =  concat(replace(trim(title_in), ' ', '-'),'-',v_count);
            end if;

            return v_return;
        end;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks. i had defined delimiter only above function.

Comment: Welcome @Algorismus:)